# Unable to Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am unable to connect to Microsoft Teams, receiving the following error. Unsure if this is due to a dependent module not existing on the device that is causing this?

> Connect-MicrosoftTeams : Unable to load DLL 'IEFRAME.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

On checking the teams module installed it looks up to date and installed correctly, output of get-module below. Is connecting to microsoft teams somehow reliant on internet explorer/edge installation for this .dll (or manually downloading said .dll and registering it?). I wish to avoid unnecessary changes on the device in question and am hesitant to throw solutions to see what will stick (small changes cannot be enacted without cutting through red tape).

> ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
> ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
> Script     5.1.0      MicrosoftTeams                      {Add-TeamChannelUser, Add-TeamUser, Connect-MicrosoftTeams, Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams...}

I have run an update-module on the microsofteams module to no avail.
Able to run locally on my machine without issue.

Thanks for taking a look folks.

Comment: IEFRAME.dll is part of Internet Explorer.  You may have IE installed on your machine but not in Microsoft Team which uses Edge.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to a lack of ieframes.dll on the server.
However ieframes.dll is only needed in the event certificate based authentication was used.
You can get around this by using account based authentication or registering the .dll necessary.